# Though the exception is caught in the config parser the error traceback is shown in python

Tags: python, exception, configparser

I am fetching the values from the configfile. To make sure my program handles any exceptions that can occur I have my config read operation in try except block as follow:

```
def __getConfigDetails(self):
        try:
            self.username = config.get("plugin_haproxy", 'user')
            self.hostname = config.get("plugin_haproxy", 'host')
            self.filelocation = config.get("plugin_haproxy", 'filepath')

        except ConfigParser.NoOptionError as error:
            logging.error(error)
            print "Error in options Name", error
        except ConfigParser.NoSectionError as error:
            logging.error(error)
            print "Error in sections Name", error
```

After getting the details with this I am calling another function which needs the above value as an arguments. We know that the one of the value will of course not be available but how do we handle such situations,Why is the exceptions not handling it

```
self.executeCommand(self.username, self.hostname, self.filelocation)
```

The program works great but Suppose if the user changed the options in config file and changed **user to username** Of course the method is suppose to handle it since we are handling **ConfigParser.NoOptionError** exception.

Here,in my program it is throwing the exceptions BUT also throwing the error traceback as below,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 59, in main
    cons.PLUGIN_CONFIG_PATH, finaloutput, finallogs)
  File "/home/tara/taraproject/checkaccessEnv/project2/plugins/plugin_haproxy/plugin_haproxy.py", line 51, in run
    self.__getConfigDetails()
  File "/home/tara/taraproject/checkaccessEnv/project2/plugins/plugin_haproxy/plugin_haproxy.py", line 23, in __getConfigDetails
    self.username = config.get("plugin_haproxy", 'user')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 340, in get
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'user' in section: 'plugin_haproxy'
```

I just want the exceptions print to be displayed,Why is it so ?

> I know I can handle this situations by using if clause on
>   secondfunction ie, __executeCommand to make sure if it runs than only
>   move further but this might not be the solution since I have
>   exceptions doing the work forhead, What is the best way to solve such
>   problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was 
the exceptions occurred and the try block where I am fetching the config value could not get it since it didnt execute and next I am calling the functions 
**

> self.executeCommand(self.username, self.hostname, self.filelocation)

with the parameters that dont have a value set thus the error occured so in the previous functions **def __getConfigDetails(self):** I added sys.exit() as below.

```
def __getConfigDetails(self):
        try:
            self.username = config.get("plugin_haproxy", 'user')
            self.hostname = config.get("plugin_haproxy", 'host')
            self.filelocation = config.get("plugin_haproxy", 'filepath')
            logging.info('Config Read Success')
        except ConfigParser.NoOptionError as error:
            logging.exception(error)
            print "Error in options Name", error
            sys.exit(1)
        except ConfigParser.NoSectionError as error:
            logging.error(error)
            print "Error in sections Name", error
            sys.exit(1)
```

I hope this is the right way of doing